# GraphqlPlayground::Rails::Engine Server cannot be reached on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, graphql, graphql-playground

Locally GraphQL Playground is running fine, but when deployed to Heroku it starts to show error message below as well as 'Server cannot be reached' status.

When I try to call queries and mutations they are working as expected, but error is still visible.

routes.rb

```
mount GraphqlPlayground::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphql_playground", graphql_path: "graphql#execute"
```

initializers/graphql_playground.rb

```
GraphqlPlayground::Rails.configure do |config|
  config.headers = {
    'X-Auth-Header' => ->(view_context) { "123" }
  }
  config.title = "Playground"
  config.csrf = true
  config.playground_version = "latest"
  config.settings = {
    "schema.polling.enable": false
  }
end
```

Is that a configuration problem or there is something else to it?

[Screenshot GraphQL Playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLARL.png)

Comment: Any chance Heroku strips non-standard headers?